# dynamically change of Navigation bar in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css

I am using bootstrap nav bar with CodeIgniter.
Now In my application, I want to change the `<li>` class to active dynamically for each page.
So I can know I am on which page currently. this is working fine, but the issue I'm facing is when I click 
any other link like "about us" or "service" etc.. it should show active on about us, or service etc and 
should not show active on the home homepage but in my case, it's showing active for about us or service page etc but
along with that it is showing active page on home also even tough m not on home page, where it should show only active 
the page on about us or service like this, please can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Home.php(file in controller page)

```
    <?php  
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

    class Home extends CI_Controller {  

        public function index()  
        {  
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('index'); 
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }  

        public function about()  
        {  
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('about'); 
        $this->load->view('footer');                    
        }

        public function services()  
        {  
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('services'); 
        $this->load->view('footer');                    
        }

        public function portfolio()  
        {  
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('portfolio'); 
        $this->load->view('footer');                    
        }

        public function blog()  
        {  
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('blog'); 
        $this->load->view('footer');                    
        }

        public function contact()  
        {  
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('contact'); 
        $this->load->view('footer');                    
        }
    }  
    ?>
```

header.php(file in view page)

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/"); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="Home"){echo 'active';}?>">Home</a></li> 
        <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/About/"); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="About"){echo 'active';}?>">About Us</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/Services/"); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="Services"){echo 'active';}?>">Services</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/Portfolio/"); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="Portfolio"){echo 'active';}?>">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/Blog/"); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="Blog"){echo 'active';}?>">Blog</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/Contact/"); ?>" class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="Contact"){echo 'active';}?>">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because "Home" is always segment 1 in your structure and thus it is always active.

Change the logic like so:

```
    <li role="presentation"><a href="<?php echo site_url("Home/"); ?>" class="<?php if(is_null($this->uri->segment(2)){echo 'active';}?>">Home</a></li>
```